# C# Parse A Json File Into A Dynamic Object Containing An Array Of Data?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have copied the following code from an example on csharpcorner.com explaining how to assign JObject.Parse method output to dynamic object and access value as properties of dynamic object.

```
string jsonData = @"{
'FirstName':'Jignesh',
'LastName':'Trivedi'
}";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Hi ", data.FirstName, " " + data.LastName));
Console.ReadLine();
```

My question is how could I accomplish the same thing (Create multiple dynamic objects) using a json file that was an array of data like the following:

```
string jsonData = @"{ 'results': [
    'FirstName':'John',
    'LastName':'Smith'
    },
    {
    'FirstName':'Jignesh',
    'LastName':'Trivedi'}
    ]}";
```

Comment: Do you need it to be of type `dynamic` or could you have the structure be as a class?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Count the elements then just create the objects with the data using calls like the one below.

```
data.results[0].FirstName;
```